# ActiveAdmin: Make index pages link to edit action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

ActiveAdmins DSL for index pages provides a simple means to link to associations, like e.g.

```
ActiveAdmin.register Rental do

  index do
    column :user
  end
```

The users name in the created column will automatically be linked to the `show` action of the associated user.

Now if in User we disabled the show action like so:

```
ActiveAdmin.register User do
  actions :all, :except => [:show]
```

AA will still generate links to the `show` action instead of to the `edit` action, as one would expect.

Is there an easy way to specify, that AA should **always** automatically link to the associations `edit` action?

**Update:**

I found out, that the link is created in `ActiveAdmin::ViewHelpers::AutoLinkHelper.auto_url_for(resource)` but I don't see how that could be made configurable.

Answer (score 0):

This bug just got fixed in activeadmin master in this commit:

https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/pull/3754

ActiveAdmin will now link to the edit action if the show action was disabled.